# AlarmManager not working on App Upgrade

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my previous version , i scheduled alarm for every 15 min and it was working fine giving logs.I set a repeating alarm.

Here is code

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent healthSender = new Intent(context, XYZ.class);
    healthSender.setAction("com........sendhealth");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, healthSender, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 15*60000,pi);
```

Later on in new version,,..

I had to change that alarm and trigger on specific 4 particular time of day..

i changed alarm from repeating to general time.

I followed , approach that scheduling alarm for next time after it was fired.

Here is code..

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, healthSender, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + getTimeForNextHealthAlarm(), pi);
            System.out.println("////   Setting NEW ALARM ///////");
            Log.d("UtilAlarmSetter", "Alarm Set");

getTimeForNextHealthAlarm()  ==> gives times for this alarm.
```

It is working fine on my machine, but when updated on google play..

**in new version there are two cases
1) New Alarms are not working at all
2) in some cases, previous alarm that was for 15 mins, is still firing**

How can i debug this problem. as in my machine everything is working fine.
When i uninstalled and downloaded fresh app from google play, this alarm is not firing, but everything working ok when i do same from code on my machine.

**NOTE:- RequestId of Pending intent is same in both versions**

Q- While updating version should alarm be cancelled first before scheduling again??
Can it be case that while updating app on google play this alarm is not configured properly??**

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks